# Windows 10: modify Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-10

How can I add a folder (D:\MyFolder) in Navigation Pane (in Windows 10)
http://prntscr.com/n8e0dk

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to add that folder to Quick Access. If so, you should go into the folder, right click the Quick Access button and click "Pin current folder to Quick Access". You can also drag-and-drop your folder there, if you're careful about not dropping the folder into another pinned folder.

[image: picture of adding to quick qcces]

Comment: Thank you, but no, I want to add a folder, but not to Quick Access. I want a folder such as This PC, Quick Access, Dropbox

Comment: Ah, sorry. Why though? :)

Comment: I have a folder with 100 folders :) and it would be easy to access the folders there

Comment: @Dan Well, [this article](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-remove-onedrive-quick-access-homegroup-and-network-icons-from-navigation-pane-of-this-pc/) shows how to _remove_ icons from the nav pane, and it involves registry-hacking. This suggests that adding to the pane would require the same.

Comment: However, if your folder is just under D:\, then couldn't you just expand This PC? That should provide you with the same functionality.